# Flutter The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the flutter app on my iPhone simulator.

> Error (Xcode):
> ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:186:20: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.```

here is my dependancies

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
flutter_redux: ^0.10.0
dio: ^4.0.3
redux_thunk: ^0.4.0
url_launcher: ^6.1.5
modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.0
dropdown_search: ^5.0.5
flutter_html: ^2.1.5
linkable: ^3.0.1
lottie: ^2.2.0
flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
shared_preferences: ^2.0.7
device_info_plus: ^8.0.0
percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
animated_widgets: ^1.1.0
skeletons: ^0.0.3
google_mobile_ads:
firebase_core:
firebase_analytics: ^10.1.0
webview_flutter_plus:
gsheets: ^0.4.2
get_it: ^7.2.0
woocommerce_api: ^0.1.0
skeleton_loader: ^2.0.0+4
```

I've tried the following.

am using the flutter stable channel.

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter upgrade`
- by removing xCode derived data.
- also I tried to fix the error showing by changing the parameter type even it's a package, but then I've to change the code on flutter sdk too. I tried to do that too but still not luck.

Comment: can you include your code-snippet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `flutter_math_fork` is not a package that I use directly.
I had to find the issue by running `flutter pub deps` to see the dependancy graph and find the usage of the package. Then I realised that It is a dependancy of `flutter_html` then I tried to update the version of `flutter_math_fork` as well as `flutter_html` but it wasn't success. So I removed that package and used the following package `flutter_widget_from_html` as an alternative to the `flutter_html` then the problem solved.

Comment: Thanks. More comprehensive package here: flutter_widget_from_html_core

Answer (score 21):

Updating flutter_html to prerelease worked for me:

```
flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6
```

Comment: flutter_html: 3.0.0-beta.2 latest Prerelease you can find it here end of first line after title https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html

Comment: Мені допомогло теж

Answer (score 7):

Had this error after upgrading to Flutter 3.10.0. Fixed it by removing **flutter_html** and adding it again through **flutter pub add flutter_html**.

After upgrading to Flutter 3.10.0, there is a new version of flutter_html created especially for this version. At this moment it's **flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.1**

Answer (score 1):

I equally a flutter pub get pinput to get the preferred version of that package cause I realized it was part of the things making the build to crash

flutter pub add pinput