# gesture_detector_builder.dart is showing many errors suddenly in flutter run

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am getting these errors while "flutter run".

[image]

please help me if you can. I have even reset my laptop to solve this errors but could not. I have done flutter run, flutter clean ad all possible way.

Comment: You can include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) while asking question, and [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75184717/17600222) might help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error you share in the image tells what is the problem. You are trying to assign a function that has the incorrect types to what the parameter expects.

`void Function(TapDownDetails)` is different than `void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?`.

You should assign to the parameter a function with same argument type of `TapDragDownDetails` and that function should also be nullable.

Answer (score 1):

Updating flutter_html to prerelease worked for me:

```
flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6
```